# Setting default reader in paraview

Tags: paraview

When opening a file (like .h5 or .xmf) which can be read via multiple readers in Paraview, the software asks me to choose which reader I want to use. As I always use the same kind of file, I need to use the same reader all the time, and I don't want to have to select it manually every time I open a file.

Is there a way to select the default reader for a given file type in Paraview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there is not a way to do this as of ParaView 5.0.

Comment: This makes me sad, but I guess I'll have to accept your answer :(